# STM32 Anti-tamper pin deactivation

Tags: stm32

I am working on a project that uses the STM32 Cortex M3 LQFP48.
There is a pin for Anti-tamper (PC13).

I am not concerned with anti-tamper security as this is just a home project.

How can I deactivate this feature on my chip?

Comment: The part number makes it a bit easier to find which chip you are specifically talking about. A link to the datasheet and reference manual make it even easier to find the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the description of the backup control register BKP_CR:

[image: backup control register]

As you can see, if the TPE bit is not set the TAMPER pin is free to be used as general purpose IO. Only setting that bit will change the function of the pin to the tamper detection.

And the reset value of the register is 0x0, so the default value is to start as standard IO and not as tamper pin.

So under normal circumstances, you don't have to do anything special to make use of that pin.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't enable the tamper interrupt, or do anything in the tamper interrupt you don't need to do anything.

You need to activate it for anything to happen, rather than deactivate it because you're not using it.